# use ImageMagick command to draw sequence of points in c++

Tags: c++, imagemagick, draw

If I want to draw a circle at position (10,10) for size(5,5) on the image test.jpg, I could use the command

```
system("convert test.jpg -fill blue -draw \"circle 10,10,5,5\" output1.jpg");
```

Now I have a sequence of points saved in a vector pts, is there an efficient way to finish the drawing in a for loop?

Comment: what do you mean by "finish the drawing"?

Comment: rather than calling the command line by line and passing the position value one by one manually, is it possible to do something like use position variable in the command, so that I could just loop through all positions to draw circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a for-loop and given coordinates and size of your circle 
you can create a string with command which you can later pass to system again. Look at function to_string